# Printing and/or Saving RPubs post as pdf

Tags: r, pdf, save, webshot, rpubs

I attempted to save or print the [RPubs post](https://rpubs.com/Zahidasghar/LDEP) as a PDF document, but I was unsuccessful. I also experimented with the provided code, but it didn't work either as required.

```
library(webshot)
webshot(
    url     = "https://rpubs.com/Zahidasghar/LDEP"
  , file    =  "Output1.pdf"
  , vwidth  = 992
  , vheight = 744
  )
```

On the other hand, it converts the entire post into a single-page document that is not suitable for printing.

**Edited**

Also tried `wget` without any success.

Comment: If you look on page source, you will find a link to https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/620217_af09aac3d4de49e8aa4194ad29820305.html (as `iframe`. Just follow the link and print out the page or save as pdf...

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSapijaszko for very useful comment. Please change your comment to answer and highlight how to get source page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by embedding the content of the article via `iframe`. When you look on the page source(s) of RPubs articles, you will find a part like:

```html
<div id='pagebody'>
<div id='payload'>
<iframe allow='fullscreen' src='//rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/1059356_eb7073491a644e91a1a854c87ad20780.html'></iframe>
```

where `src` links to original version of the article. Follow up the link and print out/convert to pdf the pages.

Using R, something like:

```r
r <- readLines(con = "https://rpubs.com/EmilOWK/norway_math_gaps")
r <- r |> 
  subset(grepl("iframe", r))
r |>
  stringr::str_sub(start = 28, nchar(r)-11) |>
  stringr::str_replace(pattern = "src=\'", replacement = "https:")
#> [1] "https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/1059356_eb7073491a644e91a1a854c87ad20780.html"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>